Recent precog apocalypse movie
Trying to remember the name of a recent sci-fi/disaster movie, probably from the last 5-6 years (watched it on DVD).
If featured an apocalypse where someone who knew it was coming had written down a huge list of numbers that predicted future disasters, the sequence ended in EE.

The EE stood for "Everyone Else"


It sounds a lot like Knowing from 2009 starring Nicolas Cage.  In the movie they dig up an old time-capsule where they find a list of numbers that seems to represent various disasters that have already happened and some that are about to happen. To quote wikipedia about the last number:

The last number in the document appears to be "33" but they notice that it is really "EE" written backwards.

and 

 They figure out that EE also means "Everyone Else"..


That's it, I remember the school time-capsule scene.

Nicholas played the fathers role. One of my favourites!@

Good answer.. horrendous movie.
